# Script to get CPU Usage

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage, invoke-command

I am using this script to get CPU usage from multiple server

```
$Output = 'C:\temp\Result.txt'
$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Serverlist.txt'
$CPUPercent = @{
  Label = 'CPUUsed'
  Expression = {
    $SecsUsed = (New-Timespan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
    [Math]::Round($_.CPU * 10 / $SecsUsed)
  }
}
Foreach ($ServerNames in $ServerList) {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerNames -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Name, CPU, $CPUPercent, Description | Sort-Object -Property CPUUsed -Descending | Select-Object -First 15 | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $Output -Append
  }
}
```

and I am getting error

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
>   + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
>   + PSComputerName : ServerName

Can you pls assist me in this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `$Output` in your script block which you invoke on the remote computer via `Invoke-Command` and therefore is not defined when the script block is executed in the remote session.
To fix it you could pass it as parameter to the script block or define it within the script block but I guess you rather want to write the file on the initiating client rather than on the remote computer. So instead of using `Out-File` in the script block you may want to use it outside the script block like so

```
$Output = 'C:\temp\Result.txt'
$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Serverlist.txt'

$ScriptBlock = {  

    $CPUPercent = @{
      Label = 'CPUUsed'
      Expression = {
        $SecsUsed = (New-Timespan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
        [Math]::Round($_.CPU * 10 / $SecsUsed)
      }
    }  

    Get-Process | 
      Select-Object -Property Name, CPU, $CPUPercent, Description | 
      Sort-Object -Property CPUUsed -Descending | 
      Select-Object -First 15  
}

foreach ($ServerNames in $ServerList) {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerNames -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock | 
    Out-File $Output -Append
}
```

Please also notice that I moved the definition of `$CPUPercent` into the script block as this suffered from the same problem.