# CPU Usage Script

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage, invoke-command

I am also trying to get memory usage using the script mentioned below (Posted in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157249/script-to-get-cpu-usage)  -

```
$Output = 'C:\temp\Result.txt'
$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Serverlist.txt'
$ScriptBLock = {  
$CPUPercent = @{
Label = 'CPUUsed'
Expression = {
$SecsUsed = (New-Timespan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
[Math]::Round($_.CPU * 10 / $SecsUsed)

$MemUsage = @{
Label1 ='RAM(MB)' 
Expression = {$_.WS / 1MB}
}
      }
}  
Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Name, CPU, $CPUPercent, $MemUsage,
 Description | 
Sort-Object -Property CPUUsed -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 15  | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
foreach ($ServerNames in $ServerList) {
 Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBLock -ComputerName $ServerNames | 
Out-File $Output -Append
}
```

I am getting error

The value of a parameter was null; one of the following types was expected: {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}. + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand + PSComputerName : Server1

Can you pls let me know what should I correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some misplaced squiggelies. Heres the fixed code:

```
$Output = 'C:\temp\Result.txt'
$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\temp\Serverlist.txt'
$ScriptBLock = {  
  $CPUPercent = @{
    Label = 'CPUUsed'
    Expression = {
      $SecsUsed = (New-Timespan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
      [Math]::Round($_.CPU * 10 / $SecsUsed)
    }
  }
  $MemUsage = @{
    Label1 ='RAM(MB)' 
    Expression = {$_.WS / 1MB}
  }


  Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Name, CPU, $CPUPercent, $MemUsage,
  Description | 
  Sort-Object -Property CPUUsed -Descending | 
  Select-Object -First 15  | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
foreach ($ServerNames in $ServerList) {
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBLock -ComputerName $ServerNames | 
  Out-File $Output -Append
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error -

The Label1 key is not valid.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyIllegal,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Server1